# How do you multiply negative numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, addition, multiplication

This may sound stupid, but if you are trying to do something like `8*-5` (eight times negative five), you can't exactly.

In order of operations, you could do something like this: `8*(-5)`. But in javascript (and in most other languages), parentheses are the condition symbol.

Please help.

What I was *really trying to ask*, or really wonder about, was "how can the parentheses take on different meanings in the code from the perspective of the parser?" I thought the parenthesis were only for functions and if statements, so I was confused about how they were used there.

Comment: ugh… what? `8*-5` works perfectly fine in JavaScript. It equals -40. `8*(-5)` is also fine. And what's about "the condition symbol"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: You should really just try this stuff in your console before saying things that simply aren't true.  You'll see that both of your assertions are completely false.

Comment: Without putting the `*` and `-` together, and without parentheses: `var eight = 8, minusFive = -5, result = eight * minusFive;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both code in the javascript.

```
8*-5 == -40
8*(-5) == -40
```

As multiply symbol is greater precedence than minus symbol, it will be multiplied in normal math and do so in JavaScript.

Comment: What about Math.random()*-4 or something?

Comment: It applies to all cases as I mentioned multiply symbol has greater precedence so it will multiply meaning if you try 5*-5+5 then you'll get multiplied first and then addition...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - _"multiply symbol is greater precedence than minus symbol"_ - This is incorrect. The `-` operator here is the *unary negation* operator, not the binary *subtraction* operator. Multiplication is higher precedence than subtraction, but it is _lower_ precedence than unary negation. All unary operators have higher precedence than any binary arithmetic operator, including multiplication. Here is an [operator precedence chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: @MichaelGeary `3 + 4 * 5 // returns 23`. Here * has higher precedence. What you want to say is unclear to me.

Comment: The expression `3 + 4 * 5` uses the binary addition operator, just as `3 - 4 * 5` uses the binary subtraction operator. The multiplication operator is higher precedence than either addition or subtraction. However, the code in the question does not use either of these binary operators. It uses the *unary negation* operator. The same `-` symbol represents either the subtraction operator or the unary negation operator depending on the context. Subtraction and unary negation are two different operators with different precedence rules.

Comment: Put another way, multiplication is indeed higher precedence than subtraction, but multiplication is _lower_ precedence than unary negation or other unary operators. See the precedence chart linked above for full details.

Comment: I got your point. The OP was interested to know if using bracket works or without using bracket works. And in this case, the bracket has nothing to do. It's matter of operator precedence.

Comment: Worth noting that in Javascript 

`-negativeNumber * 0 = -0` instead of just `0`

For instance `-2 * 0 = -0`

Answer (score 1):

> if you are trying to do something like 8*-5 (eight times negative five), you can't exactly.

Of course you can.  Open your JavaScript console and type `8*-5`.  You get `-40`.

> In order of operations, you could do something like this: 8*(-5). But in javascript (and in most other languages), parentheses are the condition symbol.

Not sure what gave you that idea, but parenthesis can be used just fine in math operations and for setting order of operations.  Again, open your JavaScript console, type `8*(-5)` and you will see `-40`.

Comment: Sry! Might have done good to try it first.